# WordPress: Pagination for custom array

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have this snippet for creating a list of users sorted by the highest post views.

But I'm wondering of how can I create pagination for a custom array like that.

```
$topuser = array();
$avatar_size = 100;
$args = array(
    'role__in'   => array( 'contributor', 'author' ),
    'hide_empty' => '1'
);
$users = get_users( $args );

foreach ( $users as $user ) {
    $query = get_posts(
                array(
                    'author'      => $user->ID,
                    'cat'         => '3',
                    'numberposts' => -1,
                    'post_type'   => 'post',
                )
    );
    $counter = 0;
    $post_count = count_user_posts( $user->ID );

    if ( ! $post_count ) {
        continue;
    }

    // get each post of a user
    foreach ( $query as $post ){
        $views = absint( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_views_count', true ) );
        $counter += $views;

    }
    $topuser[] = array( 
        'id' => $user->ID,
        'views' => $counter,
    );
        wp_reset_query();
}

// function to sort array based on views count
function sortViews( $a, $b ) {
    return $b['views'] - $a['views'];
}

usort( $topuser, 'sortViews' ); // sort the array
$output = $topuser;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is you're not performing the request as a single database query, which means your only option would be to slice the resulting array you've created http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php the $offset parameter is what you need to look at. Normally with your database request you would perform a LIMIT query with a starting offset.

Comment: Thanks so much for fast reply, I'm still newbie with WP, if you not mind..Can you show me example within my code above, because i posted another question before but no one answered me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54382109/wordpress-top-authors-list-by-highest-post-views-with-ajax-pagination)

Comment: I don't have a local test bed to help, but you're going to have to create your own MySQL query with a JOIN and count on the posts table, once you can figure that out as a single query, then you can factor in the pagination.

Comment: mmm sound complicated for me :), ok np thanks for your help.

Comment: You can still use the array slice function on your above code's `$output`, it's not efficient to fetch the counts one at a time in a loop. `$output = array_slice( $output, 20, 10 );` starting at the 20th offset get 10 records

Comment: Can you give me an answer on this question please [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54382109/wordpress-top-authors-list-by-highest-post-views-with-ajax-pagination) , So i can understand it, Thanks for your time.